# Why is xkvbd eating newlines when I it is fed from xsel?

Tags: sed, newlines

I have this script that I assign t oa keyboard shortcut to simulate pasting through middle click:

```
#!/bin/bash
aa=0
for randstring in `xsel`
do
  if [[ "$randstring" =~ [ěščřžýáíéúůóťďň] ]]
  then
      xxx=`xsel|sed 's/ě/\\\[ecaron]/g' |sed 's/š/\\\[scaron]/g' |sed 's/č/\\\[ccaron] g' |sed 's/ř/\\\[rcaron]/g' |sed 's/ž/\\\[zcaron]/g' |sed 's/ý/\\\[yacute]/g' |sed 's/á/\\\[aacute]/g' |sed 's/í/\\\[iacute]/g' |sed 's/é/\\\[eacute]/g' |sed 's/ú/\\\[uacute]/g' |sed 's/ů/\\\[uring]/g'  |sed 's/ó/\\\[oacute]/g' |sed 's/ď/\\\[dcaron]/g' |sed 's/ň/\\\[ncaron]/g' |sed 's/ť/\\\[tcaron]/g'  |sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`
      xvkbd -text "$xxx" 2>/dev/null
      aa=1
      break
  else
    aa=0
  fi
done
if [[ $aa -eq 0 ]]
    then
        xsel | xvkbd  -file - 2>/dev/null
fi
```

I use `-text` with xvkbd when the text is in Czech (my language) because xvkbd does not understand diacritics like ě but only in form like `\[ecaron]`. Now, with this option, if there is a newline int xsel, it does not get printed with xvkbd. However, when I do

```
xx="---8<-----\nToday date is: $(date +%Y%m%d)\n---8<-----" 
xvkbd -text "$xx"  2>/dev/null
```

Newlines do get printed.

I suspect the trouble is in the last sed expression `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'`, but I do not know how to make it better. I think that I need to take care for `\n`s somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I found the problem, but the rest may still be worth reading for when you actually do want a trailing newline `...

You are missing an extra `\\` or even just `\`

```
  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\\\n/g'`
```

MORE INFO: Regarding the issue of  `$( )` vs backquotes for `command substitution`, mentioned a comment I put to this question, here is an excerpt from `man bash`.

```
When  the  old-style  backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `,  or  \.   The
first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command sub‐
stitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between  the
parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
```

---

**--** Original Post **--**

It won't print the last `\n` but it  adds intermediate `\n`  into `$xx` ...

Here is a simplified version of your last `sed` call:

```
printf '%s\n' 'a\[ecaron]' b c '\[rcaron]d' |
   sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g'
```

Output:

```
a\[ecaron]\nb\nc\n\[rcaron]d
```

The reason it doesn't have a final `\n` (in the above example) is that  there simply won't be a trailing newline char in the pattern-space for the lastline (only ones from previous line-endings, via `N`, will be there)...  `sed` will subsequently output the final newline char as it exits, but even so, it will be gobbled up by the `xx=$(command substitution)` either by `$( )` or `backticks` ...

To include a final `\n`,  it needs just one final substitution.

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;s/$/\\n/'
```

Or is it a case of you are not getting even the intermediate `\n`s?

---

Just a side note: You don't need to have umpteen *seds* calling that many processes. You can concatenate them via `;` (colon), eg. `sed 's/ě/\\\[ecaron]/g; s/š/\\\[scaron]/g; ....`  or not even use the colons and just put each substitution expression on a new line.. which allows them to line up nicely...

Comment: On the side note, it has been pointed to me before I could use `sed -e 'bla/bla' -e 'bleble'` but the thing about having each expression on a new line is very neat and readable, thanks. Thanks for the answer (even the long one) anyway.

One thing I am still unclear on is why I need so many `\ `? I mean,  with `s/\n/\\n/g`, I would expect it to catch any newline (`\n`) and replace it with one backslash (`\\ ` would do that) and then print `n`. Does sed for some reason think I am trying to escape a newline?

Comment: I've just found the *real(?)* problem this time (I hope)... It is to do with backticks vs `$( )` ... your `\\n` works fine with `$( )` but loses the newlines otherwise... (but I'm starting to phase out on this one...need sleep occasionally :) ... It works when I use `$( )` ... which, by the way, is a much preferred and encouraged (newer) style..

Comment: Using `\\n` (not `\\\\n`), `$( )` works for me, but backticks lose every intermediate newline... There is one more issue though, and that is of having to determine before you process your `xsel` data whether or not is had a trailing newline, and then selectively add (or not add) that final trailing newline via a sed expression...

Comment: I will remember `$()`, thanks for that, it works with just two backslashes now. As for the trailing `\n`, it seems to be keeping it now, so I will let it be. In case I need to test for it, I just do `xsel | grep -qE "/n$` and then act accordingly on `$?`.